# How to print "" if value of variable is null?

Tags: javascript, jtemplates

I'm rendering some HTML in which I inject the value of a textbox with javascript.
See: {$T.blob.title}

```
<input type="text" maxlength="40" size="16" id='imgtitle_{$T.blob.Id}' value='{$T.blob.title}' class="imagetitleinput" /><br />
```

However, this string may be null so the textbox shows the value `"null"` to the visitor.
How can I check (preferably inline) if the value of `{$T.blob.title}` is `null` and if so set the value of this textbox to `""`?

I'm using this template engine: http://jtemplates.tpython.com/

Comment: What template engine are you using? At a first glance this does not seem to have anything to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Add an if-statement, but don't get too messy with inline Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: If it was just JavaScript I'd say do `T.blob.title||''` (assuming the title isn't expected to be an integer, as `0` would become `''`)

Comment: If this is being generated (and `{$T.blob.title}` sounds non-javascript to me), then do the substitution in the outer language rather than in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling: I updated my question with correct template engine

Comment: Looks like the stuff between `{}` can be any expression. You could try `{$T.blob.title || ''}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work [Using Jquery]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".imagetitleinput").each(function () {
        if($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            $(this).val('NULL');
        }
    });
})
```

Though not sure if you want to use Jquery here or not.

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform this logic before your $T.blob.title variable even gets near entering the DOM. Don't start performing inline JS inside an element - it's just not good practise!

I assume you are building an object literal further up the flow? If so, check the value of $.blob.title and if it equals null then set the value to an empty string.